# Make GWT load faster during DevMode

Tags: gwt

What are the ways to make browser page refresh faster during GWT DevMode? As code gets complex DevMode becomes slower.

One of my  "performance tweak" is to add the -vmargs in the project Run Configuration, what other tweaks can we do?

Comment: I think if you searched, there is already a question addressing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Firefox, rather than Chrome - Chrome with dev mode is much slower than firefox.

Try to avoid passing into/out of JSNI - that often is quite expensive.

And, as always, more ram helps, if you can get it.

Looking to the future, according to [Ray Cromwell's recent post on google plus](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110412141990454266397/posts/iqXo5AyHkyd) (check out the comments too), GWT is moving in a direction toward where you can compile your code, and see what is happening as it runs in your original java source. Rather than speeding up the dev mode, which needs to call back and forth between JS and your Java, they are trying to speed up the draft compilation, so these source maps will make it possible debug your code with the pag running as fast as the browser will let it.